# Adding campaign members and updating opens and clicks (member status) for campaigns in Microsoft Dynamics

Tags: rest, api, dynamics-crm, integration, microsoft-dynamics

I am integrating Dynamics 365 with our product, and I have a question regarding campaign members.

When a campaign is sent from our website, a campaign with the same name is created in the CRM website, and the contacts or leads they were sent to are added as members of the campaign and their status (sent, opened, clicked) is updated.

This is the process taking place in our integration with Salesforce and other CRM websites, but I am unable to find a similar process in Microsoft Dynamics. There is no such thing as campaign member status. Even through the dynamics website, I am unable to add contacts as members of the campaign and update their status.

The only thing I could find was Campaign activities - emails associated with the campaign and adding contacts or leads to them through '/email_parties' or '/campaign_activity_parties', and in both cases they are specific to the activity and I am unable to update their status as sent, opened or clicked through the REST API.

Is there any other method of adding members to a campaign and updating their status?

Comment: I believe you need to install the Dynamics 365 for Marketing module: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/marketing/overview

Comment: @Zach Thanks a lot for the reply. I signed up for the marketing module trial and it seems to have opens and clicks for emails. I'll check if member status can be updated through API here. Seems weird that everything has to be signed up for separately.

Comment: @Zach I checked and it seems there is no proper API or API doc available for dynamics 365 for marketing yet. I was only able to get the list of marketing emails using the API but I'm unable to proceed from there.

Comment: I have never specifically used this module, but I am confident that you can do anything you want to do through the Organization Service or Web API. Usually with a marketing solutions there are Email Action records which store the actions that happened for each email following an email blast.

Comment: @Zach I can't seem to find the record related to email action for now. It seems to be a new module, and maybe that's the reason for lack of proper documentation related to this. I'll look around a bit more. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction.